# Error Based SQL Injection

Tags: sql-injection, encoding

I have a MySQL lab challenge where I send `id=1‘ and select @@version;#`  then manage to trigger an error. But the part of the error response that has my version info looks like it comes back in binary (or Unicode?).

I have to send the GET in base64 then URI encode as it’s sent from a cookie parameter.

How do I make sure the response is in ASCII? Is that kind of response actually in Unicode, and browser/burp garbling the response to make it look like binary?

Here is the unencoded parameter I am sending:

```
{"last_book":"MQ==' select @@version;#","userchl2":""}
```

Here is the injected SQL above encoded base64:

```
{"last_book":"MQ==JyBzZWxlY3QgQEB2ZXJzaW9uOyM=","userchl2":""}
```

Here is the full get request with the cookie payload injected in URL encoding:

```
GET /view_book.php?id=2 HTTP/1.1
Host: 2.challenge.sqli.site
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Referer: http://2.challenge.sqli.site/books.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: userchl2_info=%7b%22%6c%61%73%74%5f%62%6f%6f%6b%22%3a%22%4d%51%3d%3d%49%47%46%75%5a%43%42%7a%5a%57%78%6c%59%33%51%67%51%45%42%32%5a%58%4a%7a%61%57%39%75%4f%77%3d%3d%22%2c%22%75%73%65%72%63%68%6c%32%22%3a%22%22%7d
Connection: close
```

Here is a screenshot of the response:

[![GET Request and Server Response][1]][1]

Comment: So, this is a class lab, right?

Comment: BTW, your name is in the header of the image you used. I have removed it so you can make the call about what you want to do about that. You can just copy/paste the text of the response from Burp.

Comment: You know? I am trying to do that class without the full forum access and cannot see the spoilers. Been on this one for a week!! Driving me crazy.

Comment: I tried this injection too... but still sends back a much larger garbled response.
'and SELECT CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(@@version USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8);#

Response:
"væB4TÄT5B4ôådU%B45B4ôådU%BfW'6öâU4ärÆFã2$ä%U4ärWFc²